# React styled-components Navigation bar goes behind sidebar

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Appologies if this question is dumb but I've been stuck on this one for a while.
Below in the screenshots you can see my problem.
In the second image I have resized the broser and the navigation bar is totally going below the sidebar, but I want it to stop and snap at the sidebar container. What is the right way to structure my components so that the navbar with all of its elements ends at the start of the sidebar and doesn't go behind regardless of screen size.
[image]
[image]

React App file

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <Navbar />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Sidebar container

```
function Sidebar() {
    return (
        
            <Container>
              
            </Container >
     
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Sidebar container style

```
    export const Container = styled.div`
height: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  resize: horizontal;
 
`
```

Navbar

```
function Navbar() {
    return (

        <Nav>

        </Nav >

    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Navbar styles

```
export const Nav = styled.div`
width: 100%;
height: 65px;
  background-color: #3D3D3D;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're components are sitting next to each other without a container like below, but because of `position:fixed;`, `Sidebar` is out of the normal content flow, and sits on top.

```
┌───────┐ ┌──────────┐
│       │ │          │
│Sidebar│ │  Navbar  │
│       │ │          │
└───────┘ └──────────┘
```

I'd propose you revise the markup a little bit like below:

```
┌───────────────────────────┐
│     Wrapper               │
│  ┌───────┐ ┌──────────┐   │
│  │       │ │          │   │
│  │Sidebar│ │  Navbar  │   │ 
│  │       │ │          │   │
│  └───────┘ └──────────┘   │
└───────────────────────────┘
```

And you could have `Wrapper` do the overall layout (e.g. `flex` or `grid`). Then, you could determine whatever needs to be nested inside `Sidebar` or `Navbar` if any.